# Trying to add check constraint for password column but keep getting these errors

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to add a constraint for the password column to ensure each password entered is atleast 6 characters but keep getting these errors [CHECK errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnl9L.png)

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running? `select version()` can tell you.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're storing plain-text passwords, this is a **huge problem**. You should be encoding these with a password-grade hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) and you should have no way of knowing how long or short the password is when looking at the database column.

Comment: Any length constraints need to be imposed in the application layer, not the database layer. You should also test that they're not just typing in `000000`.

Comment: I am running  10.4.14-MariaDB on PHP. This is also just a project and is not actually storing real customer data.

Answer (score 0):

[ALTER TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#add-constraint) documentation shows the syntax requires a contraint name:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
ADD CONSTRAINT passwordlength
  CHECK(char_length(Passwords) >= 6)
```

Recommend not even playing with clear text passwords.If its worth learning its worth learning to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You set the tag to MySQL, so here is the correct syntax for MySQL server 8:

```sql
ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (LENGTH(Passwords) >= 6) ENFORCED;
```

This won't work on MariaDB 10, because the `ENFORCED` is not supported. In other words, it is useless.

That said, the only alternative is to use a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER t1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON customers
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.Passwords = IF(
        LENGTH(NEW.Passwords) < 6,
        NULL,
        NEW.Passwords);
```

This causes all new records to have a `NULL` password if they were too short. You would need another trigger for the `UPDATE`.

Of course, this all is **insecure**. Do not store plain-text passwords. You will not get hired / promoted. Only password hashes should be stored instead. These hashes usually have a fixed length, independent of the password's length. The hashes are usually not generated / checked by the database, but in PHP. The length check thus usually doesn't happen at the database level, but has to be moved to the application.

Comment: `SIGNAL` an error rather than silently replacing with NULL is probably a good move. [Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-we-use-SIGNAL-statement-with-MySQL-triggers)